# Is it possible to modify query of Apache Spark JDBC connector?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using PySpark to read data from an Oracle DB table.
The way I do that is:

```
 profiles = spark.read.jdbc(
            url=db_url,
            table='(select /*+ SCN_ASCENDING */ '
                  'data, sys_hashval from profiles)',
            properties=connection_details,
            predicates=predicates_list)
```

Spark translates this into a query of this form:

```
SELECT "ID","DATA"
FROM (
  select /*+ FULL(profiles) SCN_ASCENDING */ id, data, sys_hashval
  from profiles
)
WHERE sys_hashval >= 10840662 and sys_hashval < 11012736
```

Which is causing problems because the hint that is added by me to the inner sub query is not in the outer query which is added by Spark.
Is there anyway to modify the outer query? Or Spark doesn't give the ability to control that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to modify this query from the PySpark, but there are a few ways to modify the query from the database side. For example, the package `DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE` lets you swap out one query for another.

```
begin
    sys.dbms_advanced_rewrite.declare_rewrite_equivalence
    (
        name             => 'spark_rewrite_1',
        source_stmt      => q'[SELECT "ID","DATA"
FROM (
  select /*+ FULL(profiles) SCN_ASCENDING */ id, data, sys_hashval
  from profiles
)
WHERE sys_hashval >= 10840662 and sys_hashval < 11012736]',
        destination_stmt => q'[SELECT /*+ SCN_ASCENDING */ "ID","DATA"
FROM (
  select /*+ FULL(profiles) */ id, data, sys_hashval
  from profiles
)
WHERE sys_hashval >= 10840662 and sys_hashval < 11012736 and 1=1]',
        validate         => false,
        rewrite_mode     => 'TEXT_MATCH'
    );
end;
/
```

That package can be difficult to use because you have to get the *exact* text of the queries. If the literals change you'll need a separate re-write, so hopefully you can control those numbers. And the final query must have a difference other than hints, which is why I added `1=1`. You may also need privileges on the package, and may need a DBA to run this command: `grant execute on dbms_advanced_rewrite to your_username;`

If the above code doesn't work, queries can also be forced to change hints through SQL Profiles, SQL translation framework, or possibly a hint that references the outer query query block name.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle looks for the `ID` column in the subquery. That's most probably the error.

I'm not familiar with Spark, but we can try adding the primary key of `profiles` in your subquery, like so:

```sql
select /*+ FULL(profiles) SCN_ASCENDING */ data, sys_hashval, pk_name "ID"
from profiles
```

Just change `pk_name` with the primary key of your `profiles` table.

Comment: I edited my query. It wasn't copied correctly, sorry. The problem isn't that the outer query doesn't find the column. The query runs correctly. Problem is that I want the hint to be added to the outer query by spark.